# Overview of Choshen Mishpat; please recommend sefer

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

I am not familiar enough with the laws of Choshen Mishpat. Can I  please have a recommendation for a summary sefer that would give me an overview of the subject before going on to learning in Sh O Choshen Mishpat itself.

Comment: The Artscroll et al. books on the individual topics, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Laws-Ribbis-Visroel-Reisman/dp/0899061265.

Comment: @pcoz ribbis is in yoreh deah

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought of that after I added the comment. I didn't delete the comment because (a) I think the questioner means to ask how they can become more familiar with *hilchos mamanos* for practical application. (b) I think the principle is correct and this is just an example.

Answer (score 4):

The founder and trustee of Touro College as well as Dean of the Jerusalem Institute of Jewish Law, [Rabbi Emmanuel Quint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Quint), has a 10 volume series entitled ***[A Restatement of Rabbinic Civil Law](https://www.gefenpublishing.com/authorcategory.asp?id=28)*** which covers the full gamut of choshen mishpat.

To quote the blurb:

> Long accepted as the standard code of Jewish law and practice, the Shulhan Aruch was written by Rabbi Joseph Karo in 1565. Now, in an unprecedented restatement of Hoshen haMishpat, one of the four sections of the Shulhan Aruch, Rabbi Emanuel Quint brings fresh insight, modern scholarship, and succinct explication to this brilliant halachic work that will fascinate the educated layperson and advanced scholar alike. All 10 volumes are now available, completing a most valuable set in Halacha.

The Hebrew equivalent of Dayan Spitz's work that @mbloch mentioned is entitled ***Mishpetei HaTorah*** and is available on Hebrewbooks (Vol [1](https://hebrewbooks.org/47660), [2](https://hebrewbooks.org/47661) & [3](https://hebrewbooks.org/47662)).

Finally, Artscroll, not so long ago, brought out a translation of Dr. Abraham S. Abraham famous ***Nishmas Avraham***. The volume on Choshen Mishpat can be found [here](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193684.html) and it allows you to view the contents page so you can see all the subject matter that he discusses.

Comment: I would recommend you build the Rabbi Quint set as you work your way through Choshen Mishpat and get the relevant volumes based on what you are learning. Hatzlocho!

Comment: You are right, Nishmas Avraham is excellent. I'd just note that "not so long ago" is 17 years ago already ... time flies when having fun !

Comment: Wow is it that long!! I'm getting old! :-)

Answer (score 3):

[The Laws of Interpersonal Relationships](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/JTVH.html) (formerly entitled "Journey to Virtue") by R Avrhohom Ehrman is very good. It is not organized according to Choshen Mishpat but covers many relevant topics and points to the right *seifim*. Amongst others it covers

- financial damages and obligations
- honest commerce
- financial kindness
- other interpersonal laws, e.g., *lashon hara*, loving and hating others, abuse and conflict, distancing from falsehoods

Another relevant book is [Cases in monetary halacha](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/CAM1H.html) by Dayan R Tzvi Spitz which covers dozens of cases in Choshen Mishpat with appropriate references

- negligence
- renting, borrowing, supervising
- assessment and compensation
- laws of employers and employees
- partnerships
- neighborly relations
- buying, selling, lending
- tzedaka
- beit din
- returning lost objects

Answer (score 1):

The Meirat Eynayim has a Hakdama right in the sefer:

- https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9725&st=&pgnum=9

Also btw there's a full table of contents and apparently complete translation here (minus the Hakdama) that might be useful

- https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Choshen_Mishpat

Comment: What does he say in the hakdama which is pertinent?

Comment: idk, but also there are more hakdamot after it